# Why are values over 100 become negative?

Tags: printf

I'm working on a deserializer in C++. I get a stream of data and I am transferring this to a char array. At the moment, everything is working perfectly except when the value is over 100, the value I get returned becomes a negative value. For example 241 becomes -15 but values below what it seems to be 100 stay the same.

Here is the code I am running

```
char streamBuffer[1024]; //where the stream data is held
 /**code in between that transfer data stream to streamBuffer[]**/

char printBuffer[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
       sprintf(printBuffer, "streamData = %ld",streamBuffer[i]);
       PrintData(printBuffer); //prints the value
}
```

For example, my stream data could look like 1,3,5,10,241,etc.

When I get to the printData function, it gives me the correct value for any value below 100 it seems.

I've used

```
sprintf(printBuffer, "streamData = %lld",streamBuffer[i]);
```

or

```
sprintf(printBuffer, "streamData = %d",streamBuffer[i]);
```

but I am still not getting the right values.

So my output will look like this.

```
StreamData: 1
StreamData: 3
StreamData: 5
StreamData: 10
StreamData: -15
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. As a starter, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hint: `StreamData = ` already overflows the buffer of size 10 in and of itself.

Comment: @tadman thanks. I just changed char streamBuffer[1024] to unsigned char streamBuffer[1024] and it solved my problem as well as change %ld to %u.

Comment: You may want to add a self-answer with the specific fixes to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to change char streamBuffer[1024] to unsigned char streamBuffer[1024] and change %ld to %u in the sprintf statement. Now values over 100 remain the same.